# How much data can be stored in the description field of an folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to store an `base64` encode of an image into the `description` field, can I do this or is this not recommended? It seems to be able to store the data but i'm not sure how long the field is or how many characters I can put in the description.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Answer (score 1):

The description should be a short string description.  Since this is visible to the user, it doesn't make sense to store an encoded image there.

You probably want to store that as a thumbnail?

Comment: Yes I agree, the user can see it and possible edit it, but it seemed to convent. Yes its a tumbnail 100x100. I can always create a new file  that would brake my structure, there no way of storing them in a hidden field?

Comment: You could use Property instead https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties#resource . Having said that, your question "How much data can be stored...?" still applies since the documentation doesn't say.